# foxbeans plugin on netbeans

Tags: netbeans, firefox-addon

While trying to install foxbeans plugin on netbeans 6.8 I am getting this problem.
The plugin Editor Library is requested in version >= 2.10.2.10.2 but only 1.44.1.9.2 was found.
I am not able to find the above mentioned plugin that is hindering the installation of foxbeans.

Answer (score 0):

For Netbeans 6.8 please install this version http://member.teesoft.info/foxbeans/com-teesoft-foxbeans-1.0.1.33.nbm as mentioned in http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=4209

It worked for me.